# CSS Descending - Not working in Safari on Mac

Tags: css, macos, safari, descendant

i create this page:

http://fortune.beejayjayn.de/

If you open it on windows in any browser, everything is working fine. Every Browser except Safari is fine on Mac.

If you open the page in Safari 6+ (Edit:after some testing it seems to be a problem on Chrome to => seems to be webkit related?) on Mac this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZdNJ.jpg

It seems like every descending style is not working...

---

I tried to:

remove "-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);" => not the solution

---

I just compared a working css with the not working one. Anything that seems fishy?

Comment: please provide us some code to work with.

Comment: can i link the files? cause since i cant narrow it down (which i really tried!) it basically everything that is needed :/

Comment: let me rephrase: without knowing the general area that is causing the problem, there is no way to actually fix the problem. "something's wrong, someone help me" will get you nowhere, because its impossible without any information.

Comment: Okay: I can pinpoint the problem only to the Safari-Browser on OSX and the styles in the main_.css which are written down as descendant css. As an example: The sections background is getting a #slide-X .bcg{background-image:url('../img/bcg_slide-X.jpg')} background-image.

They show up everywhere except for Safari 6.1 on Mac.

Additional there are some classes changed with main.js which dont work too. I cant type it down here all, that would hit the character limit - would Images of the code help?

Comment: Okay now its hittin the chrome browser too! I guess its the webkit on OSX which is causing trouble with interpreting descending css?